# How can I extract words out of "p" tag in python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I try to extract date information(2016년 12월 21일) from outside of "p" tag. But I was stuck on the part.

This is my code tried...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
....
date = soup_inspection.find('td', class_='calendar').text
print(date)
```

Below is the html code.

```
<td colspan="2" class="calendar">
    <p>「자동차관리법」 제58조 제1항 및 동법 시행규직 제120조 제1항에 따라 중고자동차의 성능ㆍ상태를 점검하였음을 확인합니다.</p>
    2016년 12월 21일
</td>
```

Please help.

Comment: Please post the code that you have already tried

Comment: I attached, but I know it doesn't work...

Comment: use `re.sub()` to remove the `<p>` tag inside the `<td>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at the date *after* the `<p>` tag:

```
soup_inspection.find('td', {"class":"calendar"}).p.next_sibling.strip()
# '2016년 12월 21일'
```

Comment: That is what I exactly tried to get. Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help.